# $_GET with Operator Comparison in PHP

Tags: php, sql, get, comparison

I am using PHP and SQL Server.
I try to use Operator Comparison but **cannot get correct response**.
When I test the URL, there is no response.
I test the URL like this one:

```
http://example.com/artafs/get_rule_rate_insco_cvg_bundle.php?INSCO_BRANCH_CODE=AAB066 && REGION_CODE=Region1 && MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE=ALL RISK && CVG_TYPE_CODE=TPL && INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE=05 && ASSET_USAGE=P && MR_ASSET_CONDITION=NEW && ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<=0 && ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>=125000000
```

This is the details of the problem:

```
if (
    isset($_GET['INSCO_BRANCH_CODE']) &&
    isset($_GET['REGION_CODE']) &&
    isset($_GET['MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE']) &&
    isset($_GET['CVG_TYPE_CODE']) &&
    isset($_GET['INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE']) &&
    isset($_GET['ASSET_USAGE']) &&
    isset($_GET['MR_ASSET_CONDITION']) &&
    isset($_GET['ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN'])
) {
    $bcode = $_GET['INSCO_BRANCH_CODE'];
    $rcode = $_GET['REGION_CODE'];
    $cmain = $_GET['MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE'];
    $cvg = $_GET['CVG_TYPE_CODE'];
    $accode = $_GET['INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE'];
    $ausage = $_GET['ASSET_USAGE'];
    $acon = $_GET['MR_ASSET_CONDITION'];
    $apmt = $_GET['ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN'];
    $apltoe = $_GET['ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL'];

    $bcode = stripslashes($bcode);
    $bcode = $db->mssql_real_escape_string($bcode);

    $rcode = stripslashes($rcode);
    $rcode = $db->mssql_real_escape_string($rcode);

    $cmain = stripslashes($cmain);
    $cmain = $db->mssql_real_escape_string($cmain);

    $cvg = stripslashes($cvg);
    $cvg = $db->mssql_real_escape_string($cvg);

    $accode = stripslashes($accode);
    $accode = $db->mssql_real_escape_string($accode);

    $ausage = stripslashes($ausage);
    $ausage = $db->mssql_real_escape_string($ausage);

    $acon = stripslashes($acon);
    $acon = $db->mssql_real_escape_string($acon);

    $apmt = stripslashes($apmt);
    $apmt = $db->mssql_real_escape_string($apmt);

    $apltoe = stripslashes($apltoe);
    $apltoe = $db->mssql_real_escape_string($apltoe);

    $result = mssql_query("
    SELECT TOP 1
        a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN,
        a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
        a.INSURANCE_RATE,
        b.TPL_AMOUNT,
        b.PERCENTAGE,
        b.AMOUNT
    FROM
        RULE_RATE_INSCO a
        INNER JOIN RULE_RATE_INSCO_CVG b ON
            a.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE=b.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE AND
            a.REGION_CODE=b.REGION_CODE AND
            a.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE=b.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE AND
            a.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE=b.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE
    WHERE
        a.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE='$bcode' AND
        a.REGION_CODE='$rcode' AND
        a.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE='$cmain' AND
        b.CVG_TYPE_CODE='$cvg' AND
        a.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE='$accode' AND
        a.ASSET_USAGE='$ausage' AND
        a.MR_ASSET_CONDITION='$acon' AND
        a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<='$apmt' AND
        a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>='$apltoe'
    ");
}
```

Query test from SQL Server is corrected and there is no problem:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN,
    a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
    a.INSURANCE_RATE,
    b.TPL_AMOUNT,
    b.PERCENTAGE,
    b.AMOUNT
FROM
    RULE_RATE_INSCO a
    INNER JOIN RULE_RATE_INSCO_CVG b ON
        a.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE=b.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE AND
        a.REGION_CODE=b.REGION_CODE AND
        a.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE=b.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE AND
        a.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE=b.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE
WHERE
    a.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE='AAB066' AND
    a.REGION_CODE='Region1' AND
    a.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE='ALL RISK' AND
    b.CVG_TYPE_CODE='TPL' AND
    a.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE='05' AND
    a.ASSET_USAGE='P' AND
    a.MR_ASSET_CONDITION='NEW' AND
    a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<='0' AND
    a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>='125000000'
```

My explanation:
After I test using the URL and fill the param in browser there is no correct response.
But when I try the query from SQL Server there no problem.
The problem is with the comparison operator `a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<='0'`
and `a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>='125000000'`. When I use just `a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN=0` there is no problem.

The newest update but still no success:

```
$keys = array(
    'INSCO_BRANCH_CODE',
    'REGION_CODE',
    'MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE',
    'CVG_TYPE_CODE',
    'INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE',
    'ASSET_USAGE',
    'MR_ASSET_CONDITION',
    'ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN',
    'ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL'
);
function get_isset($key) {
    return isset($_GET[$key]);
}
function get_escaped($key) {
    global $db;
    return $db->mssql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_GET[$key]));
}

if (!in_array(false, array_map('get_isset', $keys))) {
    list (
        $bcode,
        $rcode,
        $cmain,
        $cvg,
        $accode,
        $ausage,
        $acon,
        $apmt,
        $apltoe
    ) = array_map('get_escaped', $keys);

    $result = mssql_query("select top 1 a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN,a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL,a.INSURANCE_RATE,
    b.TPL_AMOUNT,b.PERCENTAGE,b.AMOUNT from RULE_RATE_INSCO a inner join RULE_RATE_INSCO_CVG b on a.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE=b.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE and
    a.REGION_CODE=b.REGION_CODE and a.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE=b.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE and a.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE=b.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE
    where a.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE='$bcode'
    and a.REGION_CODE='$rcode'
    and a.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE='$cmain'
    and b.CVG_TYPE_CODE='$cvg'
    and a.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE='$accode'
    and a.ASSET_USAGE='$ausage'
    and a.MR_ASSET_CONDITION='$acon'
    and a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<='$apmt'
    and a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>='$apltoe'");

}
```

Comment: You forgot to check if `$_GET['ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL']` is set.

Comment: i already using this : isset($_GET['ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL']) am i wrong with this?

Comment: No, you’re not using this in the condition. See the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to limit the query with an integer instead of string ('125000000').

Comment: i just using this : $result = mssql_query("select * ..... where .... 
 and a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<='$apmt'
    and a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>='$apltoe'"); am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is a mess. Only one ampersand (`&`) is used to delimit the parameters, only an equals mark (`=`) is used between a parameter’s name and its value and values must be %-encoded:

```
http://example.com/artafs/get_rule_rate_insco_cvg_bundle.php?INSCO_BRANCH_CODE=AAB066&REGION_CODE=Region1&MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE=ALL%20RISK&CVG_TYPE_CODE=TPL&INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE=05&ASSET_USAGE=P&MR_ASSET_CONDITION=NEW&ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN=0&ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL=125000000
```

You should debug this by displaying `$_GET` contents via `var_dump($_GET);`.

Also you forgot to check if `$_GET['ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL']` is set. You can evade such mistakes if you format your code properly and avoid repetition. Use functions for the parts that repeat (untested):

```
$keys = array(
    'INSCO_BRANCH_CODE',
    'REGION_CODE',
    'MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE',
    'CVG_TYPE_CODE',
    'INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE',
    'ASSET_USAGE',
    'MR_ASSET_CONDITION',
    'ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN',
    'ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL'
);
function get_isset($key) {
    return isset($_GET[$key]);
}
function get_escaped($key) {
    global $db;
    return $db->mssql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_GET[$key]));
}

if (!in_array(false, array_map('get_isset', $keys))) {
    list (
        $bcode,
        $rcode,
        $cmain,
        $cvg,
        $accode,
        $ausage,
        $acon,
        $apmt,
        $apltoe
    ) = array_map('get_escaped', $keys);

    $result = mssql_query("
    SELECT TOP 1
        a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN,
        a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
        a.INSURANCE_RATE,
        b.TPL_AMOUNT,
        b.PERCENTAGE,
        b.AMOUNT
    FROM
        RULE_RATE_INSCO a
        INNER JOIN RULE_RATE_INSCO_CVG b ON
            a.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE=b.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE AND
            a.REGION_CODE=b.REGION_CODE AND
            a.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE=b.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE AND
            a.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE=b.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE
    WHERE
        a.INSCO_BRANCH_CODE='$bcode' AND
        a.REGION_CODE='$rcode' AND
        a.MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE='$cmain' AND
        b.CVG_TYPE_CODE='$cvg' AND
        a.INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE='$accode' AND
        a.ASSET_USAGE='$ausage' AND
        a.MR_ASSET_CONDITION='$acon' AND
        a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<='$apmt' AND
        a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>='$apltoe'
    ");
}
```

Also the parameter `ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL` is named contra-intuitively. You should change the name or compare to its value using `>` instead of `>=`.

Comment: i try to running again using your help. but still no success. http://example.com/artafs/get_rule_rate_insco_cvg_bundle.php?
INSCO_BRANCH_CODE=AAB066 && 
REGION_CODE=Region1 && 
MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE=ALL RISK && 
CVG_TYPE_CODE=TPL && 
INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE=05 && 
ASSET_USAGE=P && 
MR_ASSET_CONDITION=NEW && 
ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<=0 && 
ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>=125000000  the result :                   {
    "success": 0,
    "message": "Required field(s) is missing"
}

Comment: Follow all the advice in my post (fixed URL, fixed code, fixed operator) and include the result of `var_dump($_GET);` in your question. Then report if the problem is solved.

Comment: still problem Mr Palec. this is the news url that i try :http://example.com/artafs/get_rule_rate_insco_cvg_bundle.php?INSCO_BRANCH_CODE=AAB066 && REGION_CODE=Region1 && MAIN_CVG_TYPE_CODE=ALL RISK   && CVG_TYPE_CODE=TPL && INS_ASSET_CATEGORY_CODE=05 && ASSET_USAGE=P && MR_ASSET_CONDITION=NEW && ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<=0 && ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>=125000000 then i try to follow your instruction. with var_dump : function get_escaped($key) {
    global $db;
    return $db->mssql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(var_dump($_GET[$key])));
} in mssql_query i try to using > or >= still problem

Comment: the query : and a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<='$apmt'
    and a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>='$apltoe'"); or and a.ASSET_PRICE_MORE_THAN<='$apmt'
    and a.ASSET_PRICE_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL>'$apltoe'"); still problem

Comment: I think we don’t understand each other and I’m not sure if any effort I put in will fix that. Please, read what I wrote once more. I did not tell you to change the `get_escaped` function. Put `var_dump($_GET); exit 0;` at the top of your script and show the results. Also use the fixed URL from my answer, not your broken one from your question.

Comment: In the question, I removed the `var_dump` from `get_escaped`. Update your local copy of the code.

Comment: var_dump($_GET); exit(); {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}

Comment: That’s impossible. That would mean the script is not executed at all.

Comment: very confused why in sql server query there is result. but in php no result. sorry because iam not expert in php

Comment: Sorry, I’m afraid I can’t help you at the moment. I’m out of time. Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can continue debugging your issue later.

Comment: any other syntax of php that i miss?

Comment: is oke mr Palec thank you so much for your response.